# C++ Get all bytes of a file in to a char array?

Tags: c++

Given:

```
const string inputFile = "C:\MyFile.csv";
char buffer[10000];
```

How do I read the chars of the file in to the above buffer? I have been looking around online but none of the answers seem to work. They all wish to call getline().

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**NOTE:** Start with [Remy Lebeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/65863). For general file reading, this answer covers the hard way to do the job; it better matched the specific needs of this specific asker, but won't necessarily meet your needs as well as the `std::vector` and `std::istreambuf_iterator` approach Remy outlines.

---

Most of the time they are right about `getline`, but when you want to grab the file [as a stream of bytes, you want `ifstream::read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

```
// Open file
std::ifstream infile("C:\\MyFile.csv"); // and since you want bytes rather than
                                        // characters, strongly consider opening the
                                        // File in binary mode with std::ios_base::binary
// Get length of file
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
size_t length = infile.tellg();
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

// Don't overflow the buffer!
if (length > sizeof (buffer)) {
    length = sizeof (buffer);
}

// Read file
infile.read(buffer, length);
```

[Docs for `ifstream::seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)

[Docs for `ifstream::tellg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)

**NOTE:** `seekg()` and `tellg()` to get the size of the file falls into the category of "usually works". This is not guaranteed. `tellg()` only promises a number that can be used to return to a particular point. That said...

**NOTE:** The file was not opened in binary mode. There can be some behind-the-scenes character translations, for example the Windows newline of `\r\n` being converted to the `\n` used by C++. `length` can be greater than the number of characters ultimately placed in `buffer`.

**2019 rethink**

```
size_t chars_read;

// Read file
if (!(infile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)))) { // Read up to the size of the buffer
    if (!infile.eof()) { // End of file is an expected condition here and not worth 
                         // clearing. What else are you going to read?
                         // Something went wrong while reading. Find out what and handle.
    }
}

chars_read = infile.gcount(); // Get amount of characters really read.
```

- If you're looping on buffered reads until you consume the whole file, you'll want some extra smarts to catch that.
- If you want to read the whole file in one shot, and can afford to use resizable buffers, take the advice in [Remy Lebeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/65863).

Comment: According to the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/seekdir), I think you should use `ifstream::end` and `ifstream::beg` instead of `ifs::end` or `ifs::beg`.

Comment: @tjysdsg Won't matter here but advice worth following. The advantage you get from using the static member, especially going all the way back to `ios` is you can change the identifier for and type of the stream and not have to refactor as much. Zero-cost general code almost always better than specific code. Few other issues I need to clean up as well.

Answer (score 23):

Another option would be to use a `std::vector` for the buffer, then use a `std::istreambuf_iterator` to read from an `std::ifstream` directly into the `std::vector`, eg:

```
const std::string inputFile = "C:\\MyFile.csv";
std::ifstream infile(inputFile, std::ios_base::binary);

std::vector<char> buffer( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile),
                          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() );
```

Alternatively:

```
const std::string inputFile = "C:\\MyFile.csv";
std::ifstream inFile(inputFile, std::ios_base::binary);

inFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
size_t length = inFile.tellg();
inFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

std::vector<char> buffer;
buffer.reserve(length);
std::copy( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile),
           std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
           std::back_inserter(buffer) );
```

If you go with @user4581301's solution, I would still suggest using `std::vector` for the buffer, at least:

```
//open file
std::ifstream infile("C:\\MyFile.csv");
std::vector<char> buffer;

//get length of file
infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
size_t length = infile.tellg();
infile.seekg(0, infile.beg);

//read file
if (length > 0) {
    buffer.resize(length);    
    infile.read(&buffer[0], length);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're concerned with efficiency (you rejected `getline()`) then a C-style `mmap` is probably best:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

struct stat s;
stat(inputFile.c_str(), &s);
size_t file_size = st.st_size;

int fhand = open(inputFile);
char* file_buf = (char*)mmap(0, file_size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE|MAP_PRIVATE, fhand, 0);
...
munmap(file_buf, file_size);
```

Comment: Or, on Windows, which has no `mmap()`, you can use `CreateFile()`, `CreateFileMapping()`, and `MapViewOfFile()` to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer{};

    {
        std::ifstream ifs("C:\\myfile.txt", std::ios::binary); // Open the file in binary mode (It will be closed automatically)

        ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        size_t length_of_the_file = ifs.tellg();
        ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(length_of_the_file); // Allocate the buffer (It will be freed automatically)

        ifs.read(buffer.get(), length_of_the_file);
    }

    // Do something with the buffer
}
```