# File read exception while reading MAC address

Tags: c++, linux, fstream, ifstream

We have a common file operation class which will do all basic file operations. So I used same file operation class to read MAC address from Linux machine, and it throws basic_ios::clear:iostream exception.

Here is the code which will be doing the file operation

```
bool FileIO::ReadTextFile(const std::string & FileName, std::string & Contents)
{
    bool Result = false;
    std::ifstream FileObj;

    try
    {
        FileObj.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit);
        if(DoesFileExist(FileName))
        {
            FileObj.open(FileName, std::ifstream::in);

            FileObj.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
            Contents.resize(FileObj.tellg());
            FileObj.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

            FileObj.read(&Contents[0], Contents.size());
            FileObj.close();

            Result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error when reading from file : " << FileName << " "<< std::strerror(errno) << " Exception : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

I am calling this function like below,

```
std::string MACAddress;
pFOpHandler->ReadEntireTextFile("/sys/class/net/eth0/address", MACAddress);
```

It is successfully reading the MAC address, but file operation is throwing an exception and MACAddress string contains MAC address and some garbage values.

Comment: I have not checked but I would bet the problem is not being able to seek in /proc or /sys files. Since they are completely virtual in order to seek to the end the kernel would have to create the file contents, then what, save it in RAM for you to read it again?

Comment: Sounds like you might be better off with [something like the first option given in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301).

Comment: You should state the exception, and show the code that throws the exception. `FileObj.read(&Contents[0], Contents.size());` ? Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this. You'd have to add include files for fstream and sstream.

```
bool FileIO::ReadTextFile(const std::string &FileName, std::string &Contents) {
  bool Result = false;
  std::ifstream FileObj;

  try {
    FileObj.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit);
    if (DoesFileExist(FileName)) {
      FileObj.open(FileName, std::ifstream::in);
      std::stringstream FileContents;
      FileContents << FileObj.rdbuf();
      Contents = FileContents.str();

      Result = true;
    }
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << "Error when reading from file : " << FileName << " "
              << std::strerror(errno) << " Exception : " << e.what()
              << std::endl;
  }
```