# Best way to construct a dynamic array with unknown height

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I am given a file with an unknown amount of words.  I need to store this into a dynamic array for school purposes (So no vectors or anything too crazy that I haven't learned). Should I...

1. Read in from a file twice? Once for word count, second time for storing the words with now known size.
2. Store into a static array first and then try to move over into a dynamic array without blank values?
3. Save into a dynamic array with extra length and then delete extra length.

Was hoping some of you would have some insight into this before I go down a rabbit hole just to discover I can't use a certain method I planned on using.

Comment: Best thing to do is write your own simple vector class. That way you can keep reusing it until the instructor gets their head out of C and allows you to start using `vector`.

Comment: If you are using either standard C++ file APIs or the typical C APIs, you can seek to arbitrary locations in the file. In your case, you can `seek()` straight to the end and find out how large the file actually is.

Comment: Note: 3 looks attractive, but is harder to do than it looks. You can't  free part of an array. Once you make it, the size is fixed, so  you have to make another array, copy the stuff in the original array over to the new array, and then delete the original array. Note that this is basically what you would be doing to resize your simple vector if you decide to go that route.

Comment: *So no vectors or anything too crazy that I haven't learned* -- The problem with this demand is that to create a vector class as others have mentioned, one that actually works properly, requires "craziness" such as user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, destructor, maybe move constructors/move assignments, etc.  So what do you consider "craziness"?

Comment: Warning: When using seek/tell to find the size of a file you have to watch out for character substitutions when reading in text mode (the classic example is "\r\n" becomes "\n", so what you read into the buffer is not the same size as the allocated buffer) and the rare cases where the locations you are given by tell do not directly map to byte locations in the file--scary and unusual, but legal. All `std::istream::tellg` promises is a value you can use to go back to a point in a stream.

Comment: Paul is hinting at [The Rules of Three, Five, and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Learn 'em and use 'em because you can't write complicated and efficient C++ unless you follow 'em.

Comment: Alright, thank you.  I'll take a look at that!

Comment: Option 1 is probably what the professor has in mind.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with the teaching method of making someone suffer through this kind of exercise instead of teaching standard library containers as the solution first, then showing the 'old' (bad) way for comparison.

Comment: Yeah, he told us he wanted us to re-invent the wheel first :/

Comment: With that said, I think method 1 is the most straight forward.

Comment: @ttemple What you describe is not specific to programming learning at all. The goal is to show the under-the-hood reasoning that is taking place so that when the new shiny tool doesn't quite work as expected, you have some ability to reason about why. That's the idea, anyhow. Very nearly all teaching goes about it this way. Thermal dynamics starts you with the differential equations before showing the resistor (algebraic) approximation. You have to understand the Diff. Eq. to prove the resistor method as adequate.

Comment: Getting that out of the way, my example doesn't translate directly to programming. But having to do your own dynamic array once or twice is a necessary stepping stone for writing data structures, and writing data structures is necessary to get a strong understanding of how they work. Using them is always the easy part. We're talking about the difference between a C.S. degree and a tech school certificate.

Comment: If it works (and it probably will) the simplest way to do option 1 is [seek and tell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36658802/4581301). Caveat: Open the file in binary mode, something this answer doesn't do. Then to feel some code envy, look at the answer after it to see the same thing with fewer failure cases done with a `vector` in about 3 lines of code. When people go, "It's so much easier in Python!" it's often because they weren't really taught C++.

Comment: @101001 "*he told us he wanted us to re-invent the wheel first*" - that is not really a good way to teach C++. He should be teaching you how to use the standard containers FIRST, so you are comfortable with them, and since that is what everyone else uses, and then he can explain WHEN they should be used and WHY they work the way they do, if you really want to know the theory behind them.

Comment: @sweenish If the course is on learning 'programming', I generally agree with you.  If the course is specifically on programming in C++ I mostly disagree.  I more agree with Stroustroup's philosophy for teaching C++. ("Programming" - Principles and practice using C++, section 0.2.1 for reference)

Comment: @ttemple I don't have that book to reference. I will say that I have the opportunity to teach an Intro class that uses C++ this fall. While I still won't be doing "Standard Library first," I will be introducing it early and often with C++14 as the baseline and not C or C+++98 like it has been. Vectors come in after pointers and demonstrating dynamic arrays, for example. I'll also be throwing in some Python. More languages early on should help them recognize that the various languages have a lot of similarities and that learning multiple programming languages isn't so bad.

Comment: @sweenish Sounds like a solid plan.  I love C++ as a language, but there are other languages are arguably better to learn "programming".  It is easy to get lost in the syntax of C++, and it can be a minefield.