# Way to deal with multiple user arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, string, arguments, cin, getline

[Task Commands Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAqRX.png) Ok, I've progressed a bit more from my previous work but I just can't get past this issue which probably isn't that big. My task, which is basically a text file editor, requires multiple user arguments after the program begins running, ranging from let's say 1 such as "details" to 3 or 4 with random user input like display x y or savepart  x y (see attached image). My code currently takes in the first line the user inputs using cin and getline but it can only read known strings such as load userinput.txt (which is the filename), and quit and I don't know how I can store the user's entered values for variables. How do I solve this?

What basically needs to probably change is the getline under the while loop or what's written in the if statements but I've tried everything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
string secondword;
string fword;
string line;
ifstream myfile;
fstream fFile;
bool running = true;
int x;
int length;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    
    while (running) {   
        getline(cin, fword);    //Reads first line user inputs

        //if first word equals laod command load file to memory
        if (fword == "load userinput.txt") {
           ifstream myfile("userinput.txt", ifstream::binary);

            myfile.seekg(0, myfile.end); //Searches till end of file
            length = myfile.tellg();    //Sets length as total number of chars in file
            myfile.seekg(0, myfile.beg); //Searches from the beginning

            char* buffer = new char[length];   //Allocates file memory to pointer

            cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... " << endl;
            myfile.read(buffer,length); //reads file and compares buffer size with legnth size
            if (myfile)
                cout << "All characters read and stored in memory sucessfully" << endl;
            else
                cout << "error: only " << myfile.gcount() << " can be read" << endl;;
            myfile.close();
        }
 
        //Quit
        if (fword == "quit") {
            running = false;    //Breaks while loop statement
            cout << "User has quit the program" << endl;
        }
        
        //Clear all lines in text
        if (fword == "clear all") {
            fFile.open("userinput.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
            fFile.close();
            cout << "All lines have been cleared" << endl;
        }

        //Display All Text
        if (fword == "display text") {
            myfile.open("userinput.txt", ios::in);
            while (getline(myfile, line)) { //read data from file object and put it into string.
                cout << line << endl; //print the data of the string
            }
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301) for a much, much smarter way to read an entire file into memory.

Comment: A simple solution is to have two modes: Edit and command. In command mode, you parse the user's input looking for and executing known commands. In edit mode you look for a special key code to transition to command mode and everything else the user types goes into a buffer and ultimately into the file when the save command is given.

Comment: And thinking on this a bit more, a `std::string` is probably a better storage medium in this case than a `std::vector`. It's easier to do text manipulation on a `string` than a `vector`. `string`'s built for the job.

Comment: I'll suggest you to use a [commaind line parser](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts) or [this](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11) for command parsing.