# Reading a wav file returns 0 bytes

Tags: c++, io, fread, stdio

So I'm reading from .wav file but it returns 0 bytes.

````cpp
    FILE *pFile = fopen("file.wav", "r");
    if (pFile == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open wave file";
        return 1;
    }

    long lSize = ftell (pFile);
    char *p = new char[lSize];
    size_t bytesRead = fread(p, 1, lSize, pFile); // 0 bytes ```
````

Comment: Someone edited to C. I put C++

Comment: This isn't C++, this is C.

Comment: inspired from an example on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: @Andy This is almost C, theres a cout in there. So I mostly agree with you ;)

Comment: C doesn't have a `new` operator either.

Comment: Then use `ifstream`... no reason to Frankenstein it.

Comment: No reason to do a lot of things. If you're rocking the C++, [check out this wizardry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301). I've linked to the second answer because it's a better fit than the first. If you have a "No `vector`" policy and have to go old-school, then look at the first.

Comment: Unrelated, but why - WHY - use C style programming for memory management when you have C++ at your hands? Don't replace `malloc` with `new`. Use a C++ container and get rid of that manual memory management. If _very rarely_ pays off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to seek to the end before getting the file position, then rewind:

```
FILE *pFile = fopen("file.wav", "rb");
if (pFile == nullptr)
{
    cout << "Unable to open wave file";
    return 1;
}

fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END); // <----- ADD THIS -------<

long lSize = ftell (pFile);

rewind(pFile); // <----- AND THIS -------<

char *p = new char[lSize];
size_t bytesRead = fread(p, 1, lSize, pFile);
```

Make sure you open as read-binary. "rb" -- look at `fopen` method.

Comment: not quite...still getting 0. but I see what you did there. it's essential to bring the index back to the beginning prior to reading from it...

Comment: @Pokloha -- what do you mean "not quite" -- this is how you do it. I have been doing it this way for 20+ years.

Comment: sorry. I meant it didn't work

Comment: @Pokloha -- open as "rb", re-read my answer

Comment: I did use `rb`...

Comment: @Pokloha -- then your file is empty. Look at the length of `file.wav` in Windows explorer

Comment: it's 1.1 MB....

Comment: @Pokloha -- did you add this line?: `fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);`

Comment: i literally copied your code to make sure I don't miss anything and it didn't work

Comment: @Pokloha -- i'm starting to think you are goofing with me. Do a absolute path to the file, i.e: `"c:\\users\\you\\desktop\\file.wav"`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UgL7Wi7

Comment: using absolute path worked

Comment: how come relative path wasn't working even though it was able to "open" the file?

Comment: @Pokloha -- because you have an empty file named `na.wav` sitting next to your program.

Comment: what do you mean by an "empty file" here? wasn't it referring to the same file as the absolute path?

Comment: @Pokloha -- no. Do a search on your entire disk for "na.wav" you will find an empty file somewhere on your disk. Could you please accept this answer if this helped you?

Comment: ah, so it created an empty file in the project location whereas I was trying to refer to the one inside `Src` file, yea?

Comment: @Pokloha -- i upvoted it so it got it back to zero. don't know why people downvote. it was a good question.

Comment: @Pokloha I can see two immediate reasons for the downvote:The question lacks a [mre]. Andy had to pull the information needed to get to the bottom of the problem out of you over the course of about 20 comments. All that information should have been in the question from the start. Next and just as likely is insufficient debugging/research. Reading documentation for `ftell` will have told you that `ftell` gives where you are in a file, not the size of the file.

Comment: Though on third thought, how to get the size of a file has been asked and answered hundreds of times. I posted a link to one in the comments under the question that does everything you wanted in about 3 lines of code and handles all of the memory management for you. I'm kind of surprised no one dupe-hammered this shut.

Comment: @user4581301 -- probably because user wanted it in C, even though it's tagged C++. That's why it slightly annoyed me as well (using `fopen`, `char*`)

Comment: the main issue that led to these many comments was uncertainty of the absolute path of the file...which solved the issue

Comment: Solved half of the issue. You had two problems. The obvious one to everyone who didn't sit around until the end is the failure to correctly compute the size of the file. The position indicator was never moved from the beginning of the file, so of course you would get zero. No one knew about the second problem until Andy pulled it out of you.