# Issues and Err0r Levels

Tags: c++

I'm building an GUI application.

When there is an issue and something happens, I can log the issue and present it to the user. If the error is FATAL, then the app quits and doesn't show anything. If it is ERROR, then I just present the issue to the user.

My question is in some code like this:

```
char* data = static_cast<char*>(malloc(size));
if (!data)
{
    // What to put for errorlevel?
    log(ERRORLEVEL, "failed malloc");
}
```

, which is a failed malloc, should it be FATAL or ERROR?

I had to put a 0 in the title because stackoverflow wouldn't let me have "Error" in the title.

Comment: It depends on the context. I'd suggest you simply throw an exception.

Comment: An Error is something you might be able to recover from and continue safely running. A Fatal Error is an Error that you cannot recover from.

Comment: So should a failed malloc be fatal or simply an error?

Comment: Depends on just how much you needed that memory and how likely your program is to run out of memory. If it should never run out of memory, you've probably got a leak that needs to be addressed by the programmers. I'd probably exit the program in this case to force the problem to be solved before the program is released to users.  If the program is a memory hog throwing buffers all over the place and running out of memory is expected and survivable behaviour, log it and carry on.

Comment: You're right. My program shouldn't allocate big buffers, so I'm going to fatally crash the app.

Comment: Looks completely opinion-based to me. The only objective thing affecting this is whether you can even display a message box (or write to log) if you run out of memory.

Comment: Side note: Have you considered using `std::vector` or `std::string` to automatically manage your memory for you? They can greatly reduce the odds of ever encountering this problem.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You're right.

Comment: @user4581301 I should probably do that. However, I'm kind of stupid and for some reason feel like that would have a performance impact.

Comment: The performance impact is usually about as heavy as all the extra checking you need in order to make sure that A) `malloc` didn't fail and B) the memory was correctly returned. I've seen some math libraries where the extra initialization cost of a `vector` was detrimental, but that's pretty rare. I'd start with a memory-managing container class and then profile the program. If the extra overhead is a problem, you'll see it pretty fast.

Comment: Why `malloc` with a bolted-on cast instead of just `new`?

Comment: @user4581301 You're right. I will do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @tadman I use `malloc` because I have to read some file, or other stuff.

Comment: Unless you absolutely need compatibility with C code that uses `free`, just use `new`. In both cases you get a block of usable memory, but with `new[]` you don't have to cast, reducing typing errors.

Comment: @tadman Well there would be a slight performance hit from using new [] because it sets all to zero.

Comment: I'd challenge you to measure this performance hit as it's bound to be inconsequential in most applications that do a trivial number of allocations. Unless you're doing a million allocations per second you can probably forget about it. If you are you probably need a custom allocator, something `new` supports, but `malloc` does not.

Comment: No, `new` doesn't zero by default.

Comment: There are some really groovy one-liner tricks to read whole files into a `vector` without so much as knowing the file size ahead of time. [See Remy Lebeau's answer linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301)

Comment: Note that the cost of reading a file will overshadow the cost of vector initialization by whole orders of magnitude. File IO is so slow you won't even see the initialization

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought new initializes to zero. @tadman You are right, I will just switch to new. The performance will be about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) person said, if your app is known to use lots of memory and failed allocation is recoverable, then carry on.

Else if your app doesn't allocate many large buffers, than I would crash the app.