# c++ convert files into string

Tags: c++, fstream

I am a C++ beginner and I need to convert some sort of files into string.
The file extensions that I have to convert are mp3, avi, png, pdf, xls.

Is there any single method I can use to convert any type of file into a string? The purpose is to apply encryption/decryption algorithm.

Comment: Files are bytes right, you can open any file in C++ and writes its content to a file textfile, but you may not be able to understand anything.

Comment: What does it mean to convert an image into a string? What do you expect/require as output? "This is a picture of Lena."?

Comment: The purpose is to apply encryption/decryption algorithm

Comment: The string is not necessary to encrypt/decrypt. Do you want to encrypt an mp3? Do you  know what algorithm you are supposed to use?

Comment: A string is not what you're looking for. Seems like you want to open the files in binary mode, read the byes into memory, and do stuff with them. Search for those kind of terms.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need human-readable input then. Generic [`std::istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) will work, but you're better off if you wrap it up with [some slick helpers such as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301) Remy's first example is about as close as you'll get to a one-liner.

Comment: I see, thank you all, I will look for that, and yes I know which algorithm I should use for encryption

Comment: While it is possible to read a binary file into a `std::string`, encryption operates on bytes, not strings. So, if you have encryption code that takes binary data as input as a string, find a better encryption code.

Comment: The point of confusion is likely a function that looks something like `int encrypt(const char * input, int len, char * output, int maxlen)`.  Since a `char` is always a byte, you'll often see functions that look like they consume a string that actually want binary information. Really they should be asking for `unsigned char *` or a `uint8_t *`, but old habits die hard and old APIs never die. Anyway `char *` is only a string if it is terminated with a nul character.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to represent binary data as a string is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

There must be some ready-to-use implementations.

Comment: I don't believe anyone can validly answer the original question without clarifying information. We could throw different binary encodings at them all day, but we won't know if it solves their issue.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I tend to agree with you. Just answered what was asked, without making assumptions on the OP's needs. Have been downvoted for that, too :)

Comment: @user4581301 :) that why I didn't do it this time