# Read binary file matrix with header in C++ (which is fortran output)

Tags: c++, file-io, fortran, binaryfiles

I have a binary file that has something like a header, and then it's proceeded by the actual matrix. Actually, the binary file is a fortran output, structured like:

```
      OPEN(UNIT=IUN43,..., FORM='UNFORMATTED',ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=IRETLEN) 
      WRITE(IUN43,REC=1) "Description text"
      WRITE(IUN43,REC=2) IRECL, ICOLS, IROWS
      WRITE(IUN43,REC=3) I1,I2
      WRITE(IUN43,REC=4) DLAT, DLON, DH
      WRITE(IUN43,REC=5) ITY,ITM,ITD
      WRITE(IUN43,REC=6) I3,I4,I5
      WRITE(IUN43,REC=7) DF
C Loop over IRETREC     
      WRITE(IUN43,17023,REC=IRETREC) I1,I2,D1,D2,D3,...
```

everything `I` is integer, `D` is double. It's very important legacy code, there's nothing I can do about it. `REC` is different line in the output file. My only experience with binary files is with fortran.

I try to read this in my c++ program. After reading tutorials and answers on Stackoverflow, I finally have something like:

```
      std::ifstream ifile(TimeSeriesDirectory1+TimeSeriesFileName1, std::ios::binary);
      if (ifile.good())
      {
      // get length of file:
      ifile.seekg (0, ifile.end);
      int filelength = ifile.tellg();
      ifile.seekg (0, ifile.beg);
      char * buffer = new char [filelength];

      std::cout << "Reading " << filelength << " characters...\n";
      std::string line;
      while (std::getline(ifile, line))
      {
       std::istringstream iss(line);
       std::cout << line.substr(0,20) <<std::endl;
       //Only 20 characters to see how and if it works
      };
```

I tried with `ifile.read (line,filelength);` and `line=const_cast<char*>(buffer);` but then the code reads only 1 line, it appears.

My intention is that the code reads the header lines (1-7) that will be copied later on to the output. It could read `IRECL, ICOLS, IROWS` from the header, since the latter two are the numbers of columns and rows. Currently I'm stuck with just reading the data, since the output is:

```
    Description text
    ^@^@^@^E^@^@^@y^p2^A^A^@^@^@
    :T   ^b      ^F^\^H         
    ^YN^u4@^xj^#?   ^s?A   |^p^o
```

etc.

I learnt, that if you know that the file is fixed-size number of doubles, you could use buffer for it. But I don't now columns nor rows before running the program. Also, the idea of having header is very important.

I already have this solved using stringstream (see below for the reference), but it results in 20G-60G matrices, so anything to speed up the process and save the disk space would be appreciated. I use linux (g++ (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0, gfortran GNU Fortran (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0). It came to my mind that maybe I could use casting operators, but it appeared too confusing and I couldn't find out how to do it.

```
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while (ss>>number) 
    {
      ++columns;
      LineOfTimeSeriesFile.push_back(number);
    };
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"It's quite risky to ask this question, because there's a risk of plenty downvotes ..."_ well, you can avoid that, by presenting a [mcve] as required here, easy.

Comment: A side note: [give this a read for a better way to read in a file than seeking and allocating a buffer with `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301). What are you using that buffer for anyway? Looks like you continue reading the file with formatted IO, not reading in the whole file.

Comment: `getline` isn't the right tool when reading binary blobs of information. Any byte that is part of a number in binary could look like a newline character, and the rest of it is probably going to look like ASCII gibberish. I'm not familiar with fortran, so I'd go looking at the output file to help with my understanding of the documentation. Hopefully you do know some fortran and can save yourself some time, but I'd still look closely at the data file and write code that reads out the integers and doubles based on what you know about the size and endian of the variables.

Comment: can you post the actual file sample, perhaps encoded with base64?

Comment: The Fortran data file has a record length of `IRETLEN` file storage units. If you are not using that information, and the size of a file file storage unit, then you have precisely zero chance of reading the file correctly in C++.

Comment: As @francescalus is pointing out, the Fortran-written file will be split in chunks of `IRETLEN` bytes, containing exactly one record per chunk. Each chunk is not necessarily fully used, so, trailing garbage may be present: you need to know exactly what kind and how many variables you gotta read per chunk. In other words, you should implement in C++ a mirror of the Fortran write routine that reads in exactly the same amount of data from each record, than skips any trailing bytes to reach the next one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun problem. Hope this helps.

Two approaches are below.
The first is brute force reading the file.
The second approach is helpful if you have fortran code that reads the file.

## Approach 1

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

#define F90_REAL_SIZE (sizeof(float))
float read_fortran_real( ifstream &stream )
{
    float tmp = 0.0;
    stream.read( (char*)&tmp, F90_REAL_SIZE );
    return tmp;
}

#define F90_INT_SIZE (sizeof(int))
int read_fortran_int( ifstream &stream )
{
    int tmp = 0;
    stream.read( (char*)&tmp, F90_INT_SIZE );
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    int iretlen = 0;
    ifstream stream( "data.raw", ios::out | ios::binary );
    if(!stream) {
        cout << "Cannot open file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string hdrstr;
    getline( stream, hdrstr, '\0' );
    cout<<"HEADER:"<<hdrstr<<endl;
    iretlen = hdrstr.length() + 1;
    while( stream.peek() == '\0' )
    {
        iretlen++;
        stream.get( );
    }
    cout<<"IRETLEN:"<<iretlen<<endl;

    int irecl = read_fortran_int( stream );
    int icols = read_fortran_int( stream );
    int irows = read_fortran_int( stream );
    stream.seekg( iretlen - 12, ios_base::cur );

    int i1 = read_fortran_int( stream );
    int i2 = read_fortran_int( stream );
    stream.seekg( iretlen - 8, ios_base::cur );

    float dlat = read_fortran_real( stream );
    float dlon = read_fortran_real( stream );
    float  dh = read_fortran_real( stream );
    stream.seekg( iretlen - 12, ios_base::cur );

    int ity = read_fortran_int( stream );
    int itm = read_fortran_int( stream );
    int itd = read_fortran_int( stream );
    stream.seekg( iretlen - 12, ios_base::cur );

    int  i3 = read_fortran_int( stream );
    int  i4 = read_fortran_int( stream );
    int  i5 = read_fortran_int( stream );
    stream.seekg( iretlen - 12, ios_base::cur );

    float  df = read_fortran_real( stream );
    stream.seekg( iretlen - 4, ios_base::cur );

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ )
    {
        int i1 = read_fortran_int( stream );
        int i2 = read_fortran_int( stream );
        float d1 = read_fortran_real( stream );
        float d2 = read_fortran_real( stream );
        float d3 = read_fortran_real( stream );
        // 20 bytes exactly
        stream.seekg( iretlen - 20, ios_base::cur );
    }

    stream.close();

    cout<<"IRECL:"<<irecl<<endl;
    cout<<"ICOLS:"<<icols<<endl;
    cout<<"IROWS:"<<irows<<endl;
    cout<<"DLAT:"<<dlat<<endl;
    cout<<"DLON:"<<dlon<<endl;
    cout<<"DH:"<<dh<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

## Approach 2

Use existing code.

```cpp
// FILE: try6C.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern"C" {
void read_header_( char* HDRSTR, int* ICOLS, int* IROWS, int* I1, int* I2, float* DLAT, float* DLON, float* DH, int* ITY, int* ITM, int* ITD, int* I3, int* I4, int* I5, float* DF, float* D1, float* D2, float* D3 );
}

int main()
{
   char HDRSTR[17] = { 0 };
   int ICOLS, IROWS, I1, I2;
   float DLAT, DLON, DH;
   int ITY, ITM, ITD, I3, I4, I5;
   float DF, D1, D2, D3;

   read_header_( HDRSTR, &ICOLS, &IROWS, &I1, &I2, &DLAT, &DLON, &DH, &ITY, &ITM, &ITD, &I3, &I4, &I5, &DF, &D1, &D2, &D3 );

   printf( "%s\n", HDRSTR );
   printf( "%d\n", ICOLS );
   printf( "%d\n", IROWS );

   return 0;
}
```

```
! FILE: try6F.f90
subroutine read_header( HDRSTR, ICOLS, IROWS, I1, I2, DLAT, DLON, DH, ITY, ITM, ITD, I3, I4, I5, DF, D1, D2, D3 )
  integer :: IUN43
  integer :: IRECL
  integer, intent(out) :: ICOLS, IROWS
  integer, intent(out) :: I1, I2
  real, intent(out) :: DLAT, DLON, DH
  integer, intent(out) :: ITY, ITM, ITD
  integer, intent(out) :: I3, I4, I5
  real, intent(out) :: DF
  real, intent(out) :: D1, D2, D3
  character(16), intent(out) :: HDRSTR
  IRECL=20
  OPEN( NEWUNIT=IUN43, FILE='data.db', ACCESS='DIRECT', RECL=IRECL, FORM='UNFORMATTED', STATUS='UNKNOWN' ) 
  READ(IUN43,REC=1) HDRSTR
  READ(IUN43,REC=2) IRECL, ICOLS, IROWS
  READ(IUN43,REC=3) I1,I2
  READ(IUN43,REC=4) DLAT, DLON, DH
  READ(IUN43,REC=5) ITY,ITM,ITD
  READ(IUN43,REC=6) I3,I4,I5
  READ(IUN43,REC=7) DF
  close(IUN43)
end subroutine
```

```bash
gfortran -c try6F.f90
g++ -c try6C.cpp 
g++ -o try6 try6C.o try6F.o -lgfortran
```

## Something Extra

A fortran program to create raw binary output.

```
program hello
  integer :: ILOOP
  integer :: IUN43
  integer :: IRECL, ICOLS, IROWS
  integer :: I1, I2
  real :: DLAT, DLON, DH
  integer :: ITY, ITM, ITD
  integer :: I3, I4, I5
  real :: DF
  real :: D1, D2, D3
  print *, 'Hello, World!'
  IRECL=20
  ICOLS=4
  IROWS=5
  DLAT=1.2
  DLON=3.4
  DH=5.6
  ITY=6
  ITM=7
  ITD=8
  I1=11
  I2=12
  I3=13
  I4=14
  I5=15
  DF=7.8
  D1=10.1
  D2=10.2
  D3=10.3
  OPEN( NEWUNIT=IUN43, FILE='data.db', ACCESS='DIRECT', RECL=IRECL, FORM='UNFORMATTED', STATUS='NEW' ) 
  WRITE(IUN43,REC=1) "Description texta"
  WRITE(IUN43,REC=2) IRECL, ICOLS, IROWS
  WRITE(IUN43,REC=3) I1,I2
  WRITE(IUN43,REC=4) DLAT, DLON, DH
  WRITE(IUN43,REC=5) ITY,ITM,ITD
  WRITE(IUN43,REC=6) I3,I4,I5
  WRITE(IUN43,REC=7) DF
  do ILOOP=8,10
      WRITE(IUN43,REC=ILOOP) I1,I2,D1,D2,D3
  end do 
  close(IUN43)
end program hello
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution that works! I've chosen the first solution, because we try to move as much as possible to C++. One comment is: I'm using double precision, so each line with real/float has to be double precision/double. I very much appreciate the short code for the binary input!