# Rcpp doesn't seem to read a binary file properly

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am trying to read a binary file using fread() and Rcpp seems to be able to read the file, given ftell() returns the proper size. When I try to print the first byte, it either returns a ☐ or nothing at all. Then RStudio crashes. This code runs perfectly fine in VSCode, but not through Rcpp.

This is how I am trying to read the file.

```
    inline void readFile(string filePath){
        //read a file using the C fopen function and store to fileData
        FILE* file = fopen(filePath.c_str(), "rb");
        
        if (file == NULL){Rcpp::stop("Cannot open file");}        


        //find size and print it to console
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); 
        int sizeOfFile = ftell(file);
        if (sizeOfFile < 1 || sizeOfFile == NULL){Rcpp::stop("Bad File size");}
        Rcpp::Rcout << "File size: " << sizeOfFile << endl;

        fileData = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*sizeOfFile);

        rewind(file);
        fread(fileData, sizeOfFile, 1, file);
    
        fclose(file);
                
        arrayPointer = fileData;
        end = fileData + sizeOfFile;
        
        if(arrayPointer == NULL){Rcpp::stop("arrayPointer is null");}
        
        Rcpp::Rcout << "ArrayPointer: " << *(uint8_t*)&arrayPointer[0] << endl; //crashes here
        // Rcpp::Rcout << "File size: " << sizeOfFile << endl;
    }
```

If I comment out where I print the first value in `arrayPointer` then program crashes in the next line after I call this function.

```
    const_array_iterator(string filePath) {

        //set up the iterator
        readFile(filePath);
        //read first 28 bytes of fileData put it into params -> metadata
        uint32_t params[7]; //Crashes here too
        memcpy(&params, arrayPointer, 28);

        arrayPointer+=32; //first delimitor is 4 bytes
        Rcpp::Rcout << "Copied params" << endl;

        magicByteSize = params[0];
        rowType       = params[1];
        nRows         = params[2];
        colType       = params[3];
        nCols         = params[4];
        valueWidth    = params[5];
        oldIndexType  = params[6];

        memcpy(&value, arrayPointer, valueWidth);
        arrayPointer += valueWidth;
        memcpy(&newIndexWidth, arrayPointer, 1);
        arrayPointer++; //this should make it point to first index
    }
```

My R code

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppClock)
library(RcppEigen)
sourceCpp("src\\playground.cpp") # The file the previous code blocks belong to
iteratorBenchmark(10, 10, 5.0)
```

This code is for use in a custom iterator, and I think it will work fine if these issues are fixed. I tried using an ifstream, but ran into similar issues. I have tried running this on linux as well as windows (WSL), but neither seem to work. I know the file is being read, as ftell() returns the correct amount of bytes. The data just seems to not be read properly from the file.

Comment: Can't help you with the R side of things, but in C++ [you can do this lil' one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301) (or any of the more brutal approaches that follow) instead of `fseek`ing all over hell's half acre and `malloc`ing data buffers like a barbarian.

Comment: With all due respect, and while I appreciate that your try to use `Rcpp`, we put exactly _zero_ between you and the OS. So "if it blows uo with Rcpp" it likely does without Rcpp too. Maybe try 'rule one' of debugging and minimise and localise.

Comment: @user4581301 I am using fread() because I found it to be slightly faster (by hundreds of ms after optimization) than using an ifstream. Also, ifstream ran into a similar issue IF it worked at all in Rcpp. I don't think this is relevant to my issue.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel you hit the nail on the head. I could have sworn it was working properly, but I guess I broke something when I tried setting this up for Rcpp benchmarking. Thank you!