# How to read little endian integers in binary files in c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, endianness

I have been trying to read a little endian binary file. I am hoping to first find an index of a string in the file from where I can start reading the data. Once I get the index, I will be looking to extract student info. I have been successful at reading strings(first and last name). However, I am not able to extract integers (age). I appreciate your help :)
Here is a sample of a section of the student info in the binary file

```
130000004A4F484E444F45
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BinaryData
{
private:
   string   age;
   string   firstName;
   string   lastName;  
public:
   BinaryData(){}
   ~BinaryData(){}
   void readStudentData(string fileName)
   {
      //open the file and get its size
      ifstream in(fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
      in.seekg(0, ios::end);
      int fileSize = in.tellg();
      in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

      //read the entire file into a buffer
      string studentBuffer;
      studentBuffer.resize(fileSize);
      in.read(&studentBuffer[0], studentBuffer.size());
      
      //move to the position where to start reading student info
      int index = studentBuffer.find("StudentInfo");
      if(index != 0 && index != std::string::npos)
      {
          //read the student info if the header is found
          age = studentBuffer.substr(index, 4); //assume we are dedicating 4 bytes for age
          index += 4;
          firstName = studentBuffer.substr(index, 10); //assume we are dedicating 10 bytes for first name
          index += 10;
          lastName = studentBuffer.substr(index, 10); //assume we are dedicating 10 bytes for last name 
          std::cout<< "The student name is: " << firstName << " " << lastName << ", they are " << age << " years old" << std::endl;
      }
      in.close();
   }
}
```

The output of my code would be:

```
The student name is: John Doe, they are **(some character)** years old
```

The expected output should be:

```
The student name is: John Doe, they are 19 years old
```

The age data looks like: 13 00 00 00 in the binary file which should translate to 19 since this is little endian.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think what you are really asking is how to read a numeric string from file and convert it into an integer.  That's not really a big/little endian problem unless you are encoding values as binary. But it sounds like you are reading a text file.

Comment: Do you have the code that wrote the file?

Comment: If these are indeed 3 bytes (or 4?) then the best thing you can do is to shift the bytes into the right location. Otherwise you'll have to assume that the system you're running the code on is little endian.

Comment: @selbie I am reading from a binary file. The binary file is little endian.

Comment: @RetiredNinja unfortunately I cant post the file :(

Comment: @Kiro - please share a sample file or show us something. Because 3 bytes for integer in any encoding is weird.

Comment: Are you executing on a little-endian or big-ending CPU?

Comment: @Kiro - then share the hex value of the first 15 bytes of your StudentInfo record and the expected "age" value.  (e.g. `StudentInfo\0x20\x42\x25"

Comment: Unrelated: [See this answer for a better way to suck a file into a library container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301). Remy uses `vector` in the example, but `string` will work just as well.

Comment: `13 00 00 00` is four bytes every time I count it. Dunno where you got three from.

Comment: Also there's no way this line `age = studentBuffer.substr(index, 3);` can possibly compile without an error if `age` is declared as an int

Comment: Side note: the odds are low, but in a binary file it's always possible that the bits line up for a false detection of StudentInfo. Usually there's a length field or a fixed size you can take advantage of to safely find the next record.

Comment: @selbie I was sharing my desired outcome. To get the code compiling and getting me the unexpected output. I had age declared as a string. I shared a sample of the input data and the expected output.

Comment: @Kiro - Please see my answer below.

Comment: If that is the actual data from the file then the next problem you're going to have is how to tell where the first name ends and the last name starts.

Answer (score 1):

A portable way to read little endian for 2's complement architectures (which is pretty much every modern computer).

Read the 4 bytes: `13 00 00 00` as follows into an integer from your character buffer.

```
uint32_t age;
memcpy(&age, studentBuffer.c_str()+index, 4);
index += 4;
```

If you're on Intel, you are likely done. Since Intel processors are Little Endian.  `age` will have the expected value. Or in this case, 0x13 == decimal 19.

If you want to portably have your code run on big-endian and little-endian hardware alike, you can do this:

```
 if (isBigEndian()) {
      // swap bytes
      uint32_t b1 = (age >> 24) & 0x000000ff;
      uint32_t b2 = (age >> 8) &  0x0000ff00;
      uint32_t b3 = (age << 8) &  0x00ff0000;
      uint32_t b4 = (age << 24) & 0xff000000;
      age = b1|b2|b3|b4;
 }
```

Where `isBigEndian()` can be written as follows:

```
bool isBigEndian() {
    uint8_t buffer[4] = {0};
    uint32_t t = 1;
    memcpy(buffer, &t, 4);
    return (buffer[0] == 0);
}
```

Comment: Corrected a few typos. Hope this helps.

Comment: this worked! Thank you for helping me figure this out :) I was running on a LE system so the memcpy did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

A shortcut.

I am assuming (pretty safe, to my taste) that the student's age is a positive number less than 255, so it fits in one byte.

Just read that byte.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to convert an integer irrespective of the system:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>

/**
 * Converts a string containing binary data into a 64-bit unsigned integer.
 * The string is interpreted in little endian format.
 * If the string contains fewer than 1 byte or more than 8 bytes, an exception is thrown.
 * 
 * @param binary_data The string containing the binary data.
 * @return The 64-bit unsigned integer representation of the binary data.
 */
uint64_t convertToUInt64(const std::string& binary_data) {
    if (binary_data.empty()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Input string must contain at least 1 byte.");
    }
    if (binary_data.size() > sizeof(uint64_t)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Input string must contain no more than 8 bytes.");
    }

    uint64_t value = 0;

    // Iterate over the string to construct the integer
    for (size_t i = 0; i < binary_data.size(); ++i) {
        // Cast each character to an unsigned byte and then shift it to the correct position
        value |= static_cast<uint64_t>(static_cast<uint8_t>(binary_data[i])) << (i * 8);
    }

    return value;
}
```

You can call this using your example binary data in a `string`:

```
int main() {
    // Binary data in a string, representing the value 19 in 3 bytes (little endian)
    std::string binary_data = "\x13\x00\x00";

    // Convert the binary data to a 64-bit unsigned integer
    uint64_t value = convertToUInt64(binary_data);

    // Output the integer value
    std::cout << "The 64-bit unsigned integer value is: " << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've shown a generic function instead of one that accepts just 3 bytes in case other sized strings are also used. If you want to have a smaller integer you can check if the integer is below a certain size, and then assign.