# Fast way to read and merge(concat) multiple text files into a new file in c++

Tags: c++, performance, text, io, file-handling

My problem

- I have multiple text files(depends on user), can be 100 or 1000
- Can be of variable size 1kb to 100mb
- I want to read all of them and merge them into a new file after some formatting.
- dont worry about formatting part

my code works fine for small problems but app crashes at 200-300mb files(can be multiple of these),
how can i make this work. the answer can be in multiple range for eg algo 1 for small file size and another for larger, im open to suggestions

This function reads a file

```
string lance::getFileContents(string path) {
    ifstream fs(path);
    fs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = fs.tellg();
    string buffer(size, ' ');
    fs.seekg(0);
    fs.read(&buffer[0], size);
    fs.close();
    return buffer.c_str();
}
```

now i am iterating over each file and storing its text in "out" variable

```
string out = "";
for (auto& chapterPath : filePath) {
    out += lance::getFileContents(chapterPath);
}
```

i then write it to a file using ofstream

im new to c++ so i appologise for any bad practice.

Comment: Do you need to have all the files open at one time?  Can you not just open one file at a time and add its contents to the merged file?

Comment: Why `return buffer.c_str();` instead of `return buffer;`? If you have a crash run your program in a debugger and find out where. If the crash isn't in your code look at the call stack to figure out where in your code the problem stared.

Comment: If you're new to C++ get in the habit of using the `std::` prefix and passing in read-only arguments as things like `const std::string& path` as this avoids unnecessary copies.

Comment: yes i need the data of all files at same time so that i can format it and save it, that is the issue

Comment: i can also open one file and append its content to merged file, but i read somewhere that append makes a copy or uses way too much memory, so im doing it this way.

Comment: "i read somewhere that append makes a copy or uses way too much memory" makes me think you need to find better reading material. It would be helpful to see a [mcve].

Comment: Side note: [What Remy does here with a `vector` you can do with a `string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301)

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend getting the OS to do the concatenating (e.g. `cat` for Linux, `type` for Windows) into a pipe, then do the formatting from standard input. The OS should be well optimized already.

Comment: As mentioned, use the system utilities that have already been tested, optimized, and works, instead of writing C++ code from scratch to do this.  I remember someone asking on an interview "how do you search a text file in C++".  The answer was "call grep from C++".

Comment: You should read *chunks*, compute them and write the result to get good performance and get a low memory footprint. Mixing read and write is especially good when the source and target devices are different. Chunks are good to mitigate the cost of copies (possibly done by the OS itself). Ideally, the size of the chunk should not be bigger than the L2 CPU cache (e.g. 256 KiB) or possibly the L3 (few MiB). The computational time of the formatting can be *overlapped* thanks to chunks, delayed writes, and prefetching done by the OS (and the standard library). This is not so easy to do though.

Comment: This is done in famous compression libraries like *zlib* for example. Most Linux basic tools often do that too.

Comment: We can’t ignore the “formatting part”; that changes the answer.  Are you writing literally the input bytes (at most with something wrapped _around_ them) or not?

Comment: formatting here means replacing few words, removing a few words removing extra spaces and blank lines etc.