# Why does my shader compilation fail with C0000 error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to compile a simple vertex shader in C++ that looks like this

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    Normal = aNormal;
    texCoord = aTexCoord;
    Fragpos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0));
}
```

I keep the source of the shader in a seperate file and I read the code from the file like this

```
    std::string readShaderSource(const char* filename)
    {

        std::string shaderCode;
        std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in);

        if (!file.good())
        {
            std::cout << "Can't read file " << filename << std::endl;
            std::terminate();
        }

        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        shaderCode.resize((unsigned int)file.tellg());
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(&shaderCode[0], shaderCode.size());
        file.close();
        return shaderCode;
    }
```

When I debug the code evetything seems fine, the value of the shader source is properly read, but the console prints out the error:

```
ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: VERTEX
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"

 -- --------------------------------------------------- --
```

Comment: Unrelated: Use [the trick Remy uses here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659103/4581301)  to read the file into `shaderCode` It's a bit safer and its less code, making it even safer because code you don't write has no bugs.

Comment: The code itself seems right; I suspect the problem lies in text encoding, like you're using UTF-16, which makes the shader compiler unable to recognize it.

Comment: @user4581301 I think the easiest way is `std::ifstream fin{ "xx" }; std::ostringstream stream; fin >> stream.rdbuf(); std::string content = std::move(stream).str();`. `content` is then all the text in the file.

Comment: I did makre sure that the encoding is correct, and it is UTF-8. Even after using the trick with reading the source in a different way it still does not work